# How to double "iPhone is Disabled" timer?

Tags: iphone

So, someone showed me a secret with the iPhone that if you enter a certain pin on the lockscreen, the iPhone will be disabled for double the amount of time. I've been searching on Google trying to find this, but I can't find anything about this. I'm kinda skeptical and I would like to know if this even exists, and maybe any other secret pin combinations that can be entered that affect the disabling of the iPhone in some way.

Honestly, I do not promote theft or anything of that nature, I would actually like to try these things on my old iPhone for fun.

Answer (score 1):

There are no secret passcode combinations to do that with original firmware from Apple. You can only find a way to tweak it after jailbreak your iPhone.